# Access Blob of Azure Storage Account via MSAL/OAuth

Tags: oauth, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-msal

I have to access and upload files to an azure storage blob via msal. So I was following and configuring my environment according to the example from Microsoft https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-azure-ad-msal. I even added the Service Principal of the App Registration to the IAM of the Storage Account to the Role "Storage Blob Data Owner" and "Storage Blob Delegator". When accessing the Blob I get the following Exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:c0de0782-701e-005b-69cd-a2c6ac000000
Time:2020-10-15T08:27:43.7229905Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: **AuthorizationPermissionMismatch**

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: c0de0782-701e-005b-69cd-a2c6ac000000
x-ms-client-request-id: a18e57f6-b22e-48c8-990b-320529a4ef13
x-ms-version: 2019-12-12
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2020 08:27:43 GMT
Content-Length: 279
Content-Type: application/xml

Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient+BlockBlob.UploadAsync_CreateResponse(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, Response response)

    Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 

    RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:c0de0782-701e-005b-69cd-a2c6ac000000 Time:2020-10-15T08:27:43.7229905Z Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.) ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch Headers: Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 x-ms-request-id: c0de0782-701e-005b-69cd-a2c6ac000000 x-ms-client-request-id: a18e57f6-b22e-48c8-990b-320529a4ef13 x-ms-version: 2019-12-12 x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2020 08:27:43 GMT Content-Length: 279 Content-Type: application/xml
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient+BlockBlob.UploadAsync_CreateResponse(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, Response response)
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient+BlockBlob.UploadAsync(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, HttpPipeline pipeline, Uri resourceUri, Stream body, long contentLength, string version, Nullable<int> timeout, byte[] transactionalContentHash, string blobContentType, string blobContentEncoding, string blobContentLanguage, byte[] blobContentHash, string blobCacheControl, IDictionary<string, string> metadata, string leaseId, string blobContentDisposition, string encryptionKey, string encryptionKeySha256, Nullable<EncryptionAlgorithmType> encryptionAlgorithm, string encryptionScope, Nullable<AccessTier> tier, Nullable<DateTimeOffset> ifModifiedSince, Nullable<DateTimeOffset> ifUnmodifiedSince, Nullable<ETag> ifMatch, Nullable<ETag> ifNoneMatch, string ifTags, string requestId, string blobTagsString, bool async, string operationName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient.UploadInternal(Stream content, BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders, IDictionary<string, string> metadata, IDictionary<string, string> tags, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Nullable<AccessTier> accessTier, IProgress<long> progressHandler, string operationName, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient+<>c__DisplayClass48_0+<<GetPartitionedUploaderBehaviors>b__0>d.MoveNext()
        Azure.Storage.PartitionedUploader<TServiceSpecificArgs, TCompleteUploadReturn>.UploadInternal(Stream content, TServiceSpecificArgs args, IProgress<long> progressHandler, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.StagedUploadInternal(Stream content, BlobUploadOptions options, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.UploadAsync(Stream content)
        WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Controllers.HomeController.CreateBlob(TokenAcquisitionTokenCredential tokenCredential) in HomeController.cs

                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);

WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Controllers.HomeController.Blob() in HomeController.cs

                string message = await CreateBlob(new TokenAcquisitionTokenCredential(_tokenAcquisition));

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I miss?

**UPDATE 1**

API Permissions of the App Registration
[image: API Permission]

Comment: Please let us know have you added Permission Azure storage/user_impersonation.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#grant-your-registered-app-permissions-to-azure-storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have granted the "Storage Blob Data Owner" role to the user account that you are using. When I granted this role to my SP only, I got the same error, after I granted this role to my login user account, everything works as excepted.
[image]

Result:

[image]

In my container:
[image]

Comment: That's the solution! Thank yout very much! I even don't need to add permissions for the Service Principal in the IAM of the storage account.